# Get XML data by attribute in array of fields

Tags: php, xml, attributes

I have a specific problem that I hope someone can help me out with. I have trawled for hours to finally get this far but feel there is a more efficient way of doing what I need. Anyway....Here is a simple version of the XML file I have:

```
<api:relationship>
    <api:related>
        <api:object>
            <api:records>
                <api:record>
                    <api:native>
                        <api:field name="publisher">
                            <api:text>Some Guy</api:text>
                        </api:field>
                        <api:field name="title">
                            <api:text>This is the title</api:text>
                        </api:field>
                        <api:field name="volume">
                            <api:text>33</api:text>
                        </api:field>
                    </api:native>
                </api:record>
            </api:records>
        </api:object>
    </api:related>
</api:relationship>
```

And I am getting all of this information this way:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($data);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('api', 'http://www.something.com/api');

foreach($xml->xpath('//api:relationship') as $header)
{
    foreach($header->children('api', true)->related->object as $items) {
        foreach ($items->records->record->native->field as $fields) { 

            if ((string) $fields->attributes()->name == 'title') {  
                echo $fields->text;
            }
        }
  }
```

I feel like that is a laughable way of doing it.

There are multiple records here and I loop through each field getting the information.

I am hoping that someone can show me how I can access that information directly.

I am trying things like:

```
$items['title']->text; 

$items->attributes()->title->text; 

foreach($items->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

But that last one doesn't make sense given that I only have one value to get, right?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath to find the specific value with a specific attribute like this:

```
$title = $xml->xpath('//api:field[@name="title"]');
```